# Hochschild cohomology and extension (counterexample?)

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $R$ a unital, associative $k$-algebra and $M$ an $R$-$R$-bimodule; it is a classical fact that $\mathrm{HH}^2(R, M)$ classifies Hochschild ($k$-algebra) extensions of $R$ by $M$. Anyway it seems strange to me not to require some compatibility on $M$ such as $cm = mc$ for every $c \in k \subset R$: for example, if we put $k = R = \mathbb{C}$ and $M = \mathbb{H}$ (quaternions) with left and right multiplications bimodule structure, how is it possible to give a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structure on $E = \mathbb{H} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ with product
$$
  (x, y) (x', y') = (xy' + yx', yy')
$$
(this would correspond to $0 \in \mathrm{HH}^2$)? For sure $z \cdot (x, y) = (zx, zy)$ or the same on the right does not work, since
$$
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      (ij, i) (k, 1) &= (k-j, i) \\
      (j, 1) (ik, i) &= (-k-j, i)
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
  \implies i \cdot [(j, 1) (k, 1)] = {?} \,.
$$

ADDENDUM: there is not such $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structure: it would be a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \to Z(E)$, where the center $Z(E)$ is the subring $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ (if my calculations are correct); now since necessarily $1 \mapsto (0, 1)$, we would have
$$
  i \mapsto (z,x)
  \quad\text{s.t.}\quad
  (0, -1) = (z, x)^2 = (2zx, x^2)
$$
and this is impossible. So, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice now that my example is misleading, since before being a $R$-$R$-bimodule, $M$ must be a $k$-module. Now it’s natural to ask whether the module structure and the induced $k$-$k$-bimodule must be compatible in order to have an algebra structure on the extension, but this answers to my question. I leave it online just for anybody who may ask the same question.